# Code error 1 cutter raster

Tags: qgis, raster, error

I want to extract a raster according to a right-of-way but despite my various attempts to choose the cutting range, the process does not succeed due to a code 1 error. What is the problem?

Message of QGIS:

```
ERROR 4: crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=xyz&url=https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Ds%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=19&zmin=0: No such file or directory
Le processus a renvoyé le code erreur 1

Chargement des couches de résultat
Les couches suivantes n'ont pas été générées correctement.
• /private/var/folders/gb/d75s9v5j4csgwkdw7_q7xpd00000gn/T/processing_NgqMJl/60d886b713374e079f50d96c7526fa20/OUTPUT.tif
Vous pouvez vérifier le Panel de messages du journal dans la fenêtre principale de QGIS pour trouver plus d'informations à propos de l'exécution de l'algorithme.
```

Comment: Did you search for the error message? If so, what did your search yield?

Comment: In internet ? I didn't find anything

Comment: It's a problem with my raster couche because it's said in the message " No such file" with the reference of the satellite image

Comment: it looks like you are using an XYZ tile service instead of an actual raster file

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It is possible to convertor a satellite map delivred by a server (that I suppose it's a XYZ tile service) to a raster file  ?

Answer (score 0):

To save the satellite image from the XYZ tile layer, in the layer panel, `right click on the  Layer > Export > Save as...`, then define file path and name, extent and resolution.

This works as long as the data provider allows you to download the data. If the suppliere blocked this option, you won't be able to save it locally. In this case, there's no other option than to contact the data provider, asking for permission.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have a error message said Impossible d'écrire le raster. Code d'erreur : fournisseur destination that it's mean that Unable to write the raster. Error code: destination supplier

Comment: That means the supplier blocked the possibility to save the data locally. So you're not entitled to save it.